# Recursively Nested Controls Crash

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So here is the thing, I spent almost a whole week trying to make this thing work and I just don't get it. If I statically code nested Expanders e.g.

```
<expander>
   <expander>
      <expander/>
   </expander>
<expander>
```

everything works but when I create that 'same' thing with nested controls the top expander works ok but the second one expands along with it and if I try to click the nested one it flips and I see this:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree. This could indicate a cycle in the tree.
```

Words cannot describe the frustration induced by XAML, here is the code snippet that causes the whole shabang:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type cpg:Category}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cpg:Category}">
                    <Border>
                        <Expander Header="{Binding DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Properties, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></ItemsControl>
                        </Expander>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

anybody ever had and solved this issue?

oh, I should add that the ItemsControl contains other objects of the same type so it becomes nested. I think it might be cause by nested bindings but after trying all different kinds of them I'm still at a loss.

update: this problem is not limited to expander, the same thing happens if I use any other container :/

update2: this only happens if the child is of the same class. I copy pasted the template and used it for a different class and it was ok :/

Comment: What is the `cpg:Category`?

Comment: Just a Class, it has nothing special in it just inherits from Systems.Windows.Controls.Control and has some DependencyProperties in it.

Comment: What's the inner exception? What's the class that it is pointing out

Comment: That's the problem the application just crashes and debugging only gives me this much info. The part that crashes is in XAML so just a big finger from Microsoft :/

Comment: What is in the Properties property? I assume you're putting cpg:Category instances into it which could lead to infinite recursion if, for example, you have an instance where two Category instances have each other in their Properties collections.

Comment: Yes, There are other cpg:Category objects in the Properties collection but there is no infinite recursion there because the view generates properly it's just that the behavior of the nested one is messed up and it crashes when I try to collapse it.